# CDI transaction management

Tags: transactions, cdi, wildfly-8, jpa-2.1

I am working on a migration project from JBoss Seam to CDI. 
Following is the technology stack :

1)WildFly 8.2.0 (CDI 1.2 with Weld as CDI provider)

2)JSF 2.2

3)JPA 2

We are using container managed JTA transactions :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="surveillenace" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/surveillenaceDS</jta-data-source> 


    <!-- other configurations not shown here -->

</persistence>
```

and using `@PersistenceContext` annotation to inject EntityManager into DAO object.

We are using `@Transaction` annotation for container managed transactions.

My questions/Understanding are below .

Can anybody confirm this since this is relatively a new area for me.

1)As I understand , CDI provides support for CMT through @Transaction interceptor. Which is the class / dependency actually implements this interceptor ? 
  Which artifacts we need to import for this in pom.xml ?

2)Since CMT is used , we don't need to demarcate any transaction and container will manage it. We only need to use EntityManager API to persist changes in Db.
  Is this understanding correct ?

```
 @Transactional
    public String finishOperation() {
        log.debug("in finishOperation() ") ;
        try {   
        //operations done on managed entities 
        //no transaction demarcation code is required here 
        dao.getEntityManager.commit();      

    }catch(Throwable xx){
    }
    }
```

3)Consider below trivial scenario executed using above configuration:

`Component1.somemethod()` - runs inside transaction and persists an entity (e.g: User) and commits transaction. 
  After this , Component2 is invoked as below :
  `Component2.somemethod()` - runs inside the transation but the entity User doesn't seem to in managed state that is  `em.contains(user)` returns false. 
                I have to merge this entity again to make it managed or reload from persistent store again

Since Seam uses `conversation-scoped entity manager` , all entity instances remain in managed state (inside persistent-context) even when any component commits a transaction and another component is invoked there after. 
But in CDI case , as I understand this is happening due to `"transaction scoped entity manager"`. Once a transaction commits , all entity instances become detached.
How can we achieve same effect as Seam using CDI ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question and clarify previous answer which was only target to Java EE 6 / CDI 1.0 while you are working with Java EE 7 / CDI 1.2

1. CDI doesn't implement transaction but JTA spec does. Yes JTA defines the interceptor binding `@Transactional` and implementation have to provide matching interceptors. As you are under WildFly, the answer to your question is in JBoss JTA implementation: Narayana. You'll find the `@Transactional(Required)` interceptor [here](https://github.com/jbosstm/narayana/blob/master/ArjunaJTA/cdi/classes/com/arjuna/ats/jta/cdi/transactional/TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java). Others are in the same package.
2. Yes, your understanding is correct.
3. Extended Persistence context are only injectable in EJB Stateful session bean. In Java EE 7 you can try to use the new [JPA 2.1 `Unsyncrhonized` mode](http://hantsy.blogspot.fr/2013/12/jpa-21-unsynchronized-persistence.html) (not tested in CDI).

Comment: of course you are right, I stand corrected, I realize that J EE 7 provides @Transactional interceptor I was for some reason thinking about CDI 1.0 I guess, sorry for somehow misinforming answer

Comment: @mariubog Then you should add a disclaimer at the top of your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

CDI does not provide transaction management implementation as part of its specs. Transaction management is left to be implemented by the programmer through the interceptors which will take care of  all the basics like starting committing etc.

Normally EntityManager lives within time span of transaction. In seam 2 you had extended persistence context, so it kept the state and beans attached to it across multiple requests. CDI does not provide that, moreover it does not recommend that due to scalability reasons.  If you look at DeltaSpike which  I would strongly suggest in case of migration from Seam2 to CDI they offer an option of extending lifespan of EntityManager promoting it to conversation scope but they do not recommend that approach as well.

---

Here you have docs for DeltaSpike treating your problem:

https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jpa.html#ExtendedPersistenceContexts

Deltaspike is great binding solution and docs are really short so I would recommend it in your case, besides it is created by the people with seam background and provides transaction management out of the box.

Comment: Your answer is correct regarding Java EE 6 but wrong in Java EE 7. JTA 1.2 provides `@Transactional` interceptor binding and the interceptor implementation as well.